# multiple nsfetchedresultscontrollers or a single one

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using core data and I am having a UITableView with dynamic number of sections.

I have an entity called dates - and it has let's say a title and a relationship which points to another entity - the id of that entity is the section data will be presented.

Which  of the best is the best approach and why?

A. Have an array of NSFetchedResultControllers - in each section I filter the data using a predicate. Then I just present the data to each section.

B. I have a single NSFetchedResultController and I fetch all the data - then inside my CellForRow I check whether I should present them or not.

C. I remove the relationship and I add an extra attribute called sectionId in my entity and use either A or B.

What is best approach  in terms of UI performance?

EDIT :

Example - I have

Entity 1 : Data

```
Data Id : 0, Title : First, (Relationship) section : 0
Data Id : 1, Title : Second, (Relationship) section : 0
Data Id : 2, Title : FisrtB, (Relationship) section : 1
```

Entiry 2 : SectionsName

```
SectionId : 0 , Name : TitleA , etc (to-many- relationhsip to Data)
SectionId : 1 , Name : TitleB , etc (to-many- relationhsip to Data)
```

So,  question is actually :

- A. Have a FRC that returns all data (3 in total) and then I should
  find which is the correct section they go to?
- B. Or have a single FRC for each section - first FRC returns the top2
  data which I can access via `indexPath.row` , the same for the second
  FRC.

Comment: Could you please state in non-abstract terms what should be displayed in the section headings? E.g. "the name of the person being dated" or something of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to reflect changes to original question**

You almost certainly should use Option B from your original question (Option A in your subsequent edit): a single `NSFetchedResultsController`, based on the `Data` entity but with table view sections determined by the `section` relationship.

Your fetched results controller can do all the hard work of dividing the objects up into the correct sections: ensure that the fetch underlying the FRC is sorted first by `section.sectionId` (or `section.name` if you prefer), and specify the FRC's `sectionNameKeyPath` as `section.sectionId` (or `section.name`).  The boilerplate FRC/tableView code will then automatically put objects into the correct sections.

The aforementioned boilerplate code:

```
#pragma mark - TableView Datasource delegate

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo  = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Data *data = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ....
    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];
    return sectionInfo.name;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sectionSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"section.sectionId" ascending:YES];
    // Add any other sort criteria
    ....
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sectionSort, ...];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:@"section.sectionId" cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - FRC delegate methods

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            break;
     }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I didn't know I can access the sectionId using the section.sectionId. I will verify the above and will mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that though you only need one attribute from the entity 2 (sectionID), you still need the relationship in order to get that entity and eventually get that attribute (sectionID). Therefore I suggest option B. The less FRCs the better. You will only need one here. In your CellForRow you will get the current entity in your fetched results array by using the indexPath. Once you have the current entity you can then now access entity 2, which is a property of the first entity. Once you have entity 2, you now have the attribute you've wanted, which is the section id of entity 2. You can now display that attribute (section id) on your table view.

Comment: But in order to use indexPath I need to filter my data based on sectionId. So, I can't just use my fetched array - I need to split it into "subarrays" let's say - is that correct?

Comment: You would use the indexPath to get the current entity in the fetched array. You could use the method below to return the entity `-(Entity *)fetchedActivityAtIndexPathSection:(NSInteger)indexPathSection
{
return [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPathSection];
}` You could also use indexpathRow if that works depending if you are using more than one section or row. Now that you have the current entity. You can now access the section id of the relationship entity of the current entity. Like NSstring* id = entity.relationshipentity.sectionID

Comment: I'm right to assume that you want to use the section id attribute of the relationship entity in the UI of your cell right? Like in a label or something

Comment: Or are you using the section id to determine whether or not to show the title of the main entity?

Comment: Ok, if I'm understanding your edit correctly, you could use option B. You would use two FRCs and then have two different fetchedObjects arrays. You would then use one fetchedObject array as the data source for  one section in your table view and the other fetchedObject array for the other section in your table view. You'd get each entity from each array using the method I gave you earlier. In your CellForRow method you can see what section you're in and use the appropriate entity. Like if section = 0 then use the title from the entity from fetchedObjects0. Thanx for your patience

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly better to use only one fetched results controller. (I agree with @Lee on this point, but I do not understand why he is recommending option B, which includes *more* FRCs.)

To summarize your data model:

```
Section <------->> Date
```

You can simply fetch the section and just adjust the `datasource` methods:

```
// number of sections
return self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count;

// number of rows in section
Section *section = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:
  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:section inSection:0]];
return section.dates.count;

// cellForRowAtIndexPath
/* create a convenience function in the Section class to return a
   sorted array from the NSSet "dates". */
Section *section = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:
  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.section inSection:0]];
Date *date = section.sortedDates[indexPath.row];
/* configure the cell based on the date object */
```

So, **`A`** is the better option.